# How to make two views clickable of RecycleView item (Xamarin.Android)?

Tags: android-recyclerview, view, xamarin.android, clickable

I have to make a replica of the following `RecyclerView`:

[image]

The `RecyclerView` contains a list of `Schedule` objects. When I click on a star, I want to change its color. When I click on the text I want to open new `Activity` with more details about the `Schedule`.

In my activity I want to have the following methods:

```
//method which gets executed when I click on a star
OnStarClick()
{
    //Get Schedule id
    //Get reference of the star so I can change its color 
}

//method which gets executed when I click on a text
OnTextClicked()
{
    //Get Schedule id
}
```

Here is my activity:

```
public class SchedulesActivity : BaseActivity
{
    RecyclerView schedulesRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager schedulesLayoutManager;
    SchedulesAdapter schedulesAdapter;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SchedulesActivity);

        List<Schedule> schedules = //Get it from database
        schedulesRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.schedulesRecyclerView);
        schedulesLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        schedulesRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(schedulesLayoutManager);
        schedulesAdapter = new SchedulesAdapter(schedules);
        schedulesRecyclerView.SetAdapter(schedulesAdapter);

    }

    OnStarClicked()
    {
    }

    OnTextClicked()
    {
    }


}
```

Here is the `Schedule` model:

```
public class Schedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public string Hour { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string LongDescription { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my `ViewHolder`:

```
public class ScheduleViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public ImageView starImageView { get; private set; }
    public TextView hourAndScheduleTextView { get; private set; }

    // Get references to the views defined in the CardView layout.
    public ScheduleViewHolder(View itemView)
        : base(itemView)
    {
        // Locate and cache view references:
        starImageView = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.starImageView);
        hourAndScheduleTextView = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.hourAndScheduleTextView);
    }
}
```

Here is my adapter:

```
public class SchedulesAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    public List<Schedule> listOfSchedules;

    public SchedulesAdapter(List<Schedule> schedules)
    {
        listOfSchedules = schedules;
    }

    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get { return listOfSchedules.Count; }
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        ScheduleViewHolder vh = holder as ScheduleViewHolder;

        vh.hourAndScheduleTextView.Text = /*listOfSchedules[position].Hour + " " + */listOfSchedules[position].ShortDescription;
    }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).
                    Inflate(Resource.Layout.ScheduleCardView, parent, false);

        ScheduleViewHolder vh = new ScheduleViewHolder(itemView);
        return vh;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add a property in Schedule class to mark if this schedule is starred. Say:

```
public bool starred { get; set; }
```

Secondly, you can add click listener in your Adapter's OnBindViewHolder method(need to unsubscribe first to avoid create multiple EventHandlers be added):

```
vh.starImageView.Click -= Image_Click;
vh.hourAndScheduleTextView.Click -= Text_Click;
vh.starImageView.Click += Image_Click;
vh.hourAndScheduleTextView.Click += Text_Click;
```

make sure your app will show different stars according to schedule's starred property, then, find clicked schedule in click method and deal with the click event:

```
private void Image_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int position = this.recyclerView.GetChildAdapterPosition((View)sender);
    Schedule sch = listOfSchedules[position];
    ...
}
private void Text_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

ps, recyclerView used in code above is passed in with the constructor.

Hope it helps.